# Macbook Pro 2019 is unable to detect more than 1 monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dock, hdmi

I have two Dell monitors and have bought `Honeywell Dock` to connect my MacBook to those two monitors

I connected one monitor to my Dock using `VGA` and another monitor to my dock using `HDMI`.

When I open up the Macbook Lid, it shows that it has detected only two monitors and it is treating both of my `Dell monitors` as one.

When I close up my Macbook Lid, the screen is seen in both of my Dell monitors and I am unable to stop the mirroring.

Need help

Comment: I found after a research that the dual monitors that are connected through my Honey well dock are been displayed by MacBook using the same display port. So both the monitors are getting the same feeds from MacBook and not been considered as two different monitors.

Comment: you may want to edit your question with a link to the dock in question, or at least the model number so other people can refer to it and help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

actually your Macbook Pro does not support more than 1 5k display. just check the resolution and get back to me.